# Android MediaPlayer attach/detach holder while playing

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a streaming app that will play a rstp video stream. The thing is I need the video to continue playing in the background (audio only) when the user moves to another activity.

In order to achieve that, I've created a static MediaPlayer object that plays the stream. The background playing works fine if I don't ever call the mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder) function. But once I set the SurfaceHolder, I cannot seem to set it back to null without the MediaPlayer pausing. This is the code in my Activity with the SurfaceView.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    StaticMediaPlayer.setHolder(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    StaticMediaPlayer.setHolder(null);
    //I've tried to do StaticMediaPlayer.setHolder(holder);
    //This actually continues the playing, but the mediaPlayer can no longer attach
    //Also, the console is flooded with errors.
}
```

The set holder function is simply a setDisplay wrapper function

```
public static void setHolder(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    //I've even tried to put mediaPlayer.start() here but it doesn't continue.
}
```

The problem is when I set the holder to be null, the video stream pauses. It resumes normally if I go back to the Activity later on.

I logged the the mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() and mediaPlayer.isPlaying() values to make sure it was still playing.

This is what it looks like when it's playing normally

```
pos: 113623 playing: true
pos: 114518 playing: true
pos: 115582 playing: true
pos: 116590 playing: true
```

And this is what it looks like when the SurfaceView is destroyed.

```
pos: 117917 playing: true //This shows that the mediaplayer is still playing.
pos: 117917 playing: true //But for some reason the position isn't progressing
pos: 117917 playing: true
pos: 117917 playing: true
```

How do I get the MediaPlayer to continue playing even if the SurfaceHolder is set to null?